# Do foods with preservatives become less toxic in the gut?

Tags: digestive-system, food

Do foods with preservatives stay digestible for longer in the gut by not rotting as much (producing less toxins)?

Comment: Hi @Jo Rijo, I edited your question to have better grammar and is now clearer. I'm not sure what you meant by the last sentence, from "doesn't start becoming toxic as fast thus the gut doesn't expel it as fast?" Can you clarify this please? Also, conservative is a poltical party, and preservatives prevent food spoilage. ;)

Comment: Please note that expulsion of feces is NOT at all due to food spoiling and becoming toxic.

Comment: @leonardo thx, I edited again, hoping it's clearer now. to clarify what you requested: I mean if the food has preservatives, then maybe it prevents the food decomposing as much as it would if it didn't have preservatives, thus not becoming as toxic as fast, thus the gut doesn't expel it as soon. hope that is clearer. But in the mean time nico has said what he said, but I don't really agree, I thought it was common knowledge that the intestines expel "stuff" that is sufficiently toxic, at least certain toxins, so...

Comment: @JoRijo no, that isn't the case :-)  I think your question is interesting but you might not get the answer you're looking for as your premise is incorrect.

Comment: what a mess :P I've done some more research and it was believed that food in the gut putrified and became toxic up until early 20th century when advances in science showed no evidence of such. source:http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2668399.

Answer (score 2):

**Do foods with preservatives take longer to digest?**

Food preservatives are either antimicrobials (e.g. sorbate, sulfite) or antioxidants (free radical scavengers such as butylated hydroxyanisole).

Digestion is initiated in the stomach by hydrochloric acid and pepsin. It continues in the small intestine with the action of numerous other enzymes including amylases, lipases and proteases. There is no obvious way that these digestive processes would be inhibited by preservatives.

Comment: Can you please provide any proof of this? It is by no means obvious that and antimicrobial could not have an effect say, on intestinal blood flow...

Comment: You can only exclude specific effects. And you're right in suspecting that not all is well with food additives. Lots of people have intolerance/allergies to them. In general however, the answer is correct and if it weren't, the food industry would be buried with paper by lawyers.

Comment: @rwst: not necessarily. An additive can modify absorption of food without having necessarily negative effects. For instance, EDTA is sometimes used as a preservative, and it does halve absorption of non-heme iron. http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/818893

Comment: Absorption isn't digestion.

Comment: Hum... well the antimicrobials, if they kill some of the helpful gut bacteria then It'd be expected that they affect the absorption rate negatively, right?

Comment: The OP referred to digestion. Digestion is the mechanical breakdown of food stuffs into small particles. To that end, @AlanBoyd has already mentioned how digestion occurs. There is nothing to suggest that food additives interfere with acid hydrolysis or other enzymatic breakdown of food materials. Whether these compounds inhibit intestinal absorption or uptake by gut microbiota is an entirely different question. Either way, as long as food can be mechanically broken down, there's nothing to suggest a healthy person cannot defecate normally.

Comment: Still, this does not exclude that a preservative could act as an inhibitor of an enzime (again, I can see how a calcium chelator such as EDTA could easily do that). I continue to say that this needs proper scientific sources.

Comment: If preservatives inhibit gut bacteria which aid in absorption, then preservatives could affect the body's ability to produce the digestive acids and enzymes in the first place.  That, in addition to the potential for more direct interference, it seems they are much more like to interfere in some way than to not interfere.